# Connect api keys to cognito users

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to connect cognito with api-key that I receive from the api-gateway.  Every user have to receive several api-keys , and I want to know if their is a way in  the api-gateway to mark that this api key belongs to  some user.

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate? 

Within API Gateway the api keys are the only identifiers for users. If Cognito could store that association (I believe they can in the new User Pools feature), then that should be embedded in the claims of the JWT tokens from Cognito. Inside API Gateway, if you set up a Cognito Authorizer then you can access all the claims of the token there.

But I'm not sure what your goal is, even if you could connect the api key with Cognito.

Comment: @JackKohn-AWS  I am try to create Service for developer. every developer signup to the service and receive api code, every request with this api code (not necessarily from the developer but also from product that use this service.  ) ,I will know that this is from this developer . What is the best way doing this?

I think use the api gateway with api-keys, save for every user the api-key. Or maybe to do it the simple way create db with map from users to api keys and every time I need new key generate randomly key.
Thanks.

Comment: @Alon How did you solve this?

Comment: @luebken I created a table in the db for this, that maps between api-key to user.